# UIScrollView is scrolling vertically when I think it should not

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

My scroll view content size is: 2304 x 44
My scroll view frame size is 768 x 44
My scroll view bounds is 768 x 44
The subview I am adding is sized 2304 x 44

But the scroll view scrolls vertically? I thought it shouldn't.  How can I prevent this?

Note, this works perfectly for my iPhone project.  But when I use the same code for the iPad, it does the weird scrolling behaviour.  Also, the subview I add get shifted down by 44 in the iPad version.  I tried to set the frame of the subview to have a position of 0, 0 before adding it, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with scroll view's automatically adding a content inset?  When I go home, I'll check if this is the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And my suspicion was correct:

```
[self setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];
```

Easy as that!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try this:

```
[_scrollview setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 44)];

[_scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2304, 44)];

[self addSubview:_scrollview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was obiously scroll vertically because you set your scroll view contain `size is 2304 * 44` right ? so there is no matter what frame(height) of your scroll view but it was matter that what height of you `contentSize.`

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying